# Protecting the op-amp against output short circuit current with a resistor

Tags: operational-amplifier, short-circuit

There is an operational amplifier [LM258WYDT](https://ru.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/lm158w-954928.pdf).

The output of the operational amplifier will produce a voltage in the range from + 12V to -12V and generate a PWM signal.

Datasheet:

> Short-circuits from the output to VCC can cause excessive heating if VCC > 15 V. The maximum output current is
>   approximately 40 mA independent of the magnitude of VCC. Destructive dissipation can result from simultaneous shortcircuits on all amplifiers.

At the input of the operational amplifier is a [TMR1222](https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/005/DOC001005246.pdf) isolated DC / DC converter with short circuit protection and a maximum output current of 85 mA.

The output of the operational amplifier may be accidentally shorted to ground.

It is necessary to protect the operational amplifier from short circuit so that it returns to normal mode after the short circuit is removed.

I was looking for protection options, one of them was a resistor connected in series to the output of the operational amplifier.

I have the opportunity to put a 680 ohm resistor.

Tell me, is this solution right?

Instead of a resistor, you can install a resettable fuse, but it will most likely distort the output signal.

Comment: Your VCC seems to be in the 'safe' region within +/15V. So why do you think you need protection at all?

Comment: The protection is related to your circuit. But opamp with a transistor in output may help you. Here shows two examples, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75649/what-does-this-op-amp-transistor-circuit-do

Comment: Why is it that the opamp output might be *accidentally* shorted to ground? How does this happen?

Comment: @Stefan Wyss, I thought that a large current from the output of the DC / DC converter would damage the operational amplifier.

Comment: @M KS, thanks for the circuit! 
@jonk, The output from the operational amplifier goes to the connector, which will be interconnected with a person. Maybe someone wants to disable it by shorting it to the ground.

Comment: @АлексГарисон Then it's "exposed" to users. I think you should include this in the question itself. It's important. The OPA454, for example, can handle the 4kV human body model on any pin and supports ***continuous*** direct shorts at its output over a wide range of source supply voltages (well above yours.) But even then, it doesn't say it can handle an ignorant ape with a screwdriver and access to an AC mains hot lead. So if you are worried about shorting to ground, are you worried about anything worse? Just asking.