# Is the op-amp supposed to be in negative feedback?

Tags: operational-amplifier, negative-feedback

[image][image]

The above circuit was simulated using Multisim-Live. A rough see through tells me that the op-amp is in positive feedback as the output of op-amp is at base and inverting terminal to the collector, which is inverted wrt the base. But the simulation doesn't show output of op-amp to saturate, i.e., +- 15V (check the probe values). Note that the op-amp is not a particular model. It's just named "5T_VIRTUAL".
A similar question was asked [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/75649/what-does-this-op-amp-transistor-circuit-do?rq=1) and my understanding holds as much as I see. I have been scratching my head all morning and I don't understand why the simulation is showing such results.

Comment: Do the transient analysis and you will see the positive feedback effect. It is normal for the simulation that they can find the bias point solution, that won't be observed in a real circuit.

Comment: So if the simulation can't find a bias point they will show results of negative feedback? This really happens?

Comment: In a normal situation when the Q1 is working in the active region, when base voltage increases, base current increases. It also causes an increase in the collector current which in turn causes a voltage drop in the collector. Thus it produces a 180 phase shift. (input positive, output negative and vice versa)  Therefore the Positive Feedback in a circuit.

Comment: But when Q1 enters the saturation region for Vb > 10V *1.4/(1.4 + 5) + 0.7 = 2.9V. This is no longer true because in saturation the collector voltage will follow the base voltage Vc = Vb - 0.5V thus we no longer have this additional phase shift hence we have negative feedback in the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the transistor is saturated the feedback is negative (an increase in base voltage results in an increase in collector voltage).

When the transistor is not saturated the feedback is negative (an increase in base voltage results in a decrease in collector voltage).

Provided V1 > 2.3V the transistor can be saturated. That is true in this case, so feedback is negative. However if the op-amp output drops below the voltage required to saturate the transistor, the feedback becomes positive and it will snap to the +10V rail at the output, with the op-amp output at the negative rail (in fact the transistor Vbe may break  down at that point, restoring negative feedback but it won't be able to get the inverting input down to 5V with typical parts).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO9h4Q.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The above circuit, with the output of the op-amp constrained to >3V or so, will stabilize with 5.00V out. If the op-amp output drops below the voltage required to saturate the transistor then the feedback becomes positive and it will latch with the op-amp output low and the output node at +10V.

---

Edit: Mathematically there is a point that is shown in your simulation that won't exist for more than an instant in the real world. It's balanced on a knife edge of positive feedback and will topple one way or the other with 2.188V at the output. If  you do a time domain simulation rather than an operating point, you should see it snap one way or the other.

Comment: How can you say that we have a negative feedback in this circuit?

Comment: Because when the output increases, the collector voltage increases and that goes to the inverting input. That's negative feedback. Because the transistor is saturated (so Vc ~= Ve  + 0.1V, and Vbe ~= 0.7V so Vc = Vb + 0.6V).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany how does "an increase in base voltage results in a decrease in collector voltage" give way to negative feedback in this case? The collector is connected to the negative pin afterall.

Comment: @Nullbyte There are two modes of operation, maybe three. If the op-amp output is high enough to saturate the transistor then the feedback is negative. And increase in base voltage results in an increase in collector voltage, as I said. If the op-amp output is lower than that voltage then the feedback is negative. It **can** stabilize with V1 > 2.3V. It won't necessarily do so.

Comment: I see your point, you are right.

Comment: Though if transistor wasn’t saturated and let’s say if base voltage decreased, collector voltage would increase, this causes inverting input to increase which should then cause output of op amp to decrease. But then this would be overall postive feedback? I usually see emitter connected to inverting input in this current sink type circuit.

Comment: Yes, it can be positive or negative. It happens to be stable if it gets in the negative feedback region.

Comment: The simulation result presented by OP shows ~5 V on the collector and ~2.2 V on the base. How does this put the transistor into saturation?

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes, that's the unstable knife-edge point. I suppose I should mention that one in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The opamp is indeed working with negative feedback, not positive, the positive pin only has a set voltage relative to ground, it doesn't change with the output of the circuit.

Basically this is a kind of [follower](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/Voltage-follower) configuration, the inverting input will follow the non inverting one if it can (which in this case can).

Comment: How does a fixed voltage on positive pin dictate the nature of feedback? I am confused now :(